# Google API and .NET Compact Framework

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am developing a Windows Mobile 6.5 (.NET Compact Framework 3.5) app that will sync the device PIM data with Google Calendar and Google Tasks services. I obviously want to make use of Google API for .NET ( http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/ ) but apparently it is designed only for the standard, desktop version of .NET Framework.

Trying to compile a CF3.5 project referencing the official API .dll's failed with messages like
*"The type 'System.Uri' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."* That would of course be the .NET Framework 2.0 .dll which cannot be referenced in a CF project.

When I downloaded API sources and tried to build them myself under CF3.5, it failed again due to references to several features that are only included in the standard .NET framework.

So my question is, what are my options here? Is there a version of Google API designed for Compact Framework that I've been grossly overlooking thus far?
And if there isn't, should I try to modify the API by removing the conflicting features, hoping they won't be needed for the functionality of my app? Should I instead ditch the pre-made API all-together and use it only for learning purposes to build my own?
Or do you have any ideas?

Any input greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

Charles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me just answer this for the future reference of others.

- There apparently isn't a CF version of Google API client libraries at this time. Was thoroughly searching for it for quite some time with no results.
- Trying to modify the client libraries yourself and accommodate them to the Compact Framework capabilities is not possible (at least not in a sensible time frame). There turned out to be way too many (often interconnected) features that would need to be removed or largely modified (or rewritten rather).
- So the correct answer is the third option - create your own libraries to access the API, making use of the well documented REST access reference (in case of Calendar API located here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/ ). Turned out to be a lot less complicated and time-demanding than I expected.